# c# Performance Issue while creating Multiple objects

Tags: c#, .net, performance

In our code, we are Mapping the domain entity into an API DTO object. In the process of converting entity is returning a huge amount of records. when we try to map those records into DTO its taking huge amount of time. 
Here is the example

```
  Class test
{
    public virtual int ID { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual BusinessDate Start { get; protected internal set; }
    protected internal virtual IList<ABC> _abc { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ABC>  ABCRange{
  get
  {
    return _abc;
  }
}

 public IEnumerable<test> GetByEmployees(IEnumerable<int> employees)
    {
      return ChunkIDsQueryForSQLServer2100Limit(employees, empArray =>
              (from ar in GetAllAsQueryable()
              where empArray.Contains(ar.Employee.ID)
              select ar).ToList());
    }
class ABC
{
    public virtual int ID { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual int DayOfWeek { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual bool StartTimeOffset { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual bool EndTimeOffset { get; protected internal set; }
    public virtual AvailabilityType Type { get; protected internal set; }

}

DTO Mapper:

    return new AvailabilityRequestCollectionResource
      {
        AvailabilityRequests = availabilityRequest.Select(AvailabilityRequestMap).ToList()
      };

     private static TEST2 AvailabilityRequestMap(TEST test)
    {
       var availabilityRequestResource = new TEST2
      {
        ID = availabilityRequest.ID,
        EmployeeID = availabilityRequest.Employee.ID,
        GeneralAvailability = AvailabilityTypeMap(availabilityRequest.ABCRange.Where(f => f.Type == AvailabilityType.General)),
        PreferredAvailability = AvailabilityTypeMap(availabilityRequest.ABCRange.Where(f => f.Type == AvailabilityType.Preferred))
      };
    }

    private static List<XYZ> AvailabilityTypeMap(IEnumerable<ABC> abc)
    {
      var availList = new List<XYZ>();

      availList.AddRange(abc.Select(x =>
        new XYZ
        {
          ID = x.ID,
          DayOfWeek = (Day)x.DayOfWeek,
          StartTimeOffset = x.StartTimeOffset,
          EndTimeOffset = x.EndTimeOffset,
          WeekNumber = 1
        }
      ));
      return availList;
    }
```

now the issue is the above method is taking almost 15sec to create say 10k objects of XYZ. Our performance bottle neck is make it as 2sec and every time the no. of objects may vary. How to make it?
We tried parallelism and tasking, those are not helping as lazy loading from domain is in place which we cannot modify.

Note : ABC and XYZ are not having same set of attributes

Thanks

Comment: Can you share how do you get your `IEnumerable<ABC>` (you're probably loading it from some `DbContext` or something), and show the definition of your `ABC` class.

Comment: We have a domain entity class which is getting loaded by a repository method. public virtual IEnumerable<ABX> abc
    {
      get
      {
        return _abc;
      }
    }  protected internal virtual IList<AvailabilityRequestRange> _availabilityRanges { get; set; }    public IEnumerable<XYZ> GetByEmployees(IEnumerable<int> employees)
    {
      return ChunkIDsQueryForSQLServer2100Limit(employees, empArray =>
              (from ar in GetAllAsQueryable()
              where empArray.Contains(ar.Employee.ID)
              select ar).ToList());
    }
is the repository call

Comment: added the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lazy loading from domain is in place

That is **almost certainly** 100% of your bottleneck.

> which we cannot modify

Then you can't fix it.

You need to challenge the lazy loading, or do something to pre-emptively load that data *efficiently* (i.e. not per-item - n+1 is brutal).

Creating 10k objects and populating them *from values that exist* should be pretty-much instantaneous (as long as the implementation doesn't do anything silly). That isn't the issue, and staring at the code that does that: won't help.

Comment: That's a very common problem with developers not familiar with lazy loading. OP should eager load related entities, and if they shared the real code, it's likely to be `dept` property.

Comment: @vijay well, yeah; that `AvailabilityRequestMap` is horrible and will cripple you; if you can't change that: you can't fix the problem.

Comment: @Marc Gravell need your inputs, i want to TEST2 class which has two <List>, One for general and one for preffered. I'm not from a c# back ground. Can you guide me on how to do this?

Comment: @vijay I don't even understand what you're asking there, so I can't comment; does it relate to the problem you're having above? if so: how?

Comment: when you say "AvailabilityRequestMap is horrible and will cripple you". I'm not sure on what kind of change I should do over there. Can you guide me on those changes?

Comment: @vijay I thought you said you *couldn't* change that; but; what you're talking about there is eager loading; it looks like you're using an ORM, so: you'll need to refer to your ORM's guidance on eager loading. Personally, I usually find this area messy and awkward, so I side-step the entire thing by designing queries that get the right data - and *all* the data I will need - in the initial query or queries, with nothing deferred or lazy. But that's a huge change.

Comment: @Marc Gravell when you say "AvailabilityRequestMap is horrible and will cripple you", what kind of changes I should do? I'm trying to map a TEST2 from test. Where test is having a IEnumurable<XYZ> which is a single list but has two status "General & preffered". Now In TEST2 I want to split the XYZ into two separate list. Can you guide me what is wrong in this and why it is taking too much of time to create the objects?

Comment: @vijay it is taking too long because you are executing lots of queries; `.Select` means "do this for every item", and inside that: you do at least two queries. So: you have *at least* a  2n+1 problem. How to fix it: either find out how to enable eager loading in your ORM, or re-engineer it from scratch to not do that in the first place - but either of those are much bigger tasks than I can answer here. This isn't a "just change these 3 lines" thing.